# Hash key as method identifier

Tags: ruby, hash

I have some ruby code like this:

```
my_hash = {
  key1: "value", 
  key2: "value"
}

def key1
  do_something
end

def key2
  do_something_else
end
```

As you can see the keys and the methods have the same name. I now want to "convert" the hash keys into method calls where the method name is the hash key

As a background, I have an ncurses menu where the hash values are the labels and I only pass the keys around. And when a menu entry is selected I want to execute the correct method without too much coding overhead like figuring out in a if or case statement which entry was selected.

Is this possible in any way? And if yes, how can I do it?

This thing is a bit hard for me to explain and I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: I personally didn't get what you mean.

Comment: And what's the value supposed to be?

Comment: I want to "print out" the hash key "key1" and that calls the method with the very same name. The value is the label of a menu but it doesn't really matter what the value is here I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to call the method with the name of the symbol:

```
my_hash.each { |k,_| send k }
```

This will call all methods in the hash. You can pick out just one and call it using `send` as well instead of iterating.

Comment: Or `my_hash.keys.each { |k| send(k) }`.

Comment: That's perfect! Thx alot. Exactly what I wanted :)